# .NET core MVC rest service not accessible from mobile devices

Tags: c#, .net, rest, iis, xamarin

I've created a .NET core rest service along with my Xamarin application.

It is hosted on a remote server with a IIS7 site, it's own domain, and has a valid ssl certificate

My problem is the web service is not accessible from any mobile devices.
I noticed this when the mobile app crashed in the android and windows emulators, when they had an active connection.

I also tested it on my own physical device samsung galaxy s7 and it also crashed.

When I navigate to the web service URL it gives 404 not found on the mobile devices, but the same exact url gives the JSON result in my web browser.

Not sure what could cause this.

Comment: are you running service locally, accessing with localhost?

Comment: @jason nope it is on a remote server with a IIS7 site, it's own domain, and has a valid ssl certificate

Comment: Can you Ping the server from your various devices ? Is this an Http error or just a network connectivity issue ? Are you connecting on your mobile device via a local IP wireless access point or via the phones data provider (one will be out via the web, and the other will be internal to the LAN - firewalls may prevent one but not the other).

Comment: @PhillipH it gives me a 403 when I access the root of the site and a 404 error when I access a specific MVC route URL (where that same url works on pc web browser) The 403/404 errors indicate it is not a network issue

Comment: @PhillipH My physical device is using my home wireless connection and the emulators will be using the LAN connection connected to my PC

Comment: you need to use wireshark or something similar to compare a working request and non-working one

Comment: Is your remote service url accessible over internet and can you access it from your mobile device's web browser which has internet connectivity?

Comment: @PankajKapare Yes that is how I've been testing, using my mobile devices web browser (after seeing the service call fail in my mobile app). It gives me a 403 forbidden error, so it has a connection and resolves the domain

Comment: @Jason How can I monitor web traffic on my mobile device? Rooting my android is not an option

Comment: from a device you would probably have to proxy traffic through your PC, or else test from a simulator

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I had a entry in my hosts file that was pointing this particular subdomain at the server that I hosted the rest service on (must have been from a long time ago and I didn't remember) but apparently our sys admin pointed the subdomain at a different test server, so my pc was getting redirected to the correct machine via hosts file, and all other devices could not find it!